# Trying to call getJSON with Knockout

Tags: javascript, json, api, knockout.js

This is my code:

```
    $('#idapiNumber').focusout(function () {

        var wellViewModel = function (APINumber, OperatorName) {
            this.APINumber = ko.observable(APINumber);
            this.OperatorName = ko.observable(OperatorName);
        };

       ko.applyBindings(new wellViewModel("", ""));

        var searchDoggrOPIAPI = "api/values";
        $.getJSON(searchDoggrOPIAPI, function (data) { data = JSON.stringify(wellViewModel()) },     function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert("Status: " + textStatus); });

    });

</script>
```

and this is my Page:

```
<label for="idapiNumber">API Number</label>
<input id="idapiNumber" data-bind="value: APINumber" type="text" placeholder="API Number" class="form-control" />

<label for="OperatorName">Operator Name</label>
<input id="OperatorName" data-bind="value: OperatorName" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

can't figure out why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is : *"You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element"* which means you are binding more than one `viewModel` to the same `DOM` `node`, which is wrong. That is probably happening because `focusout` is being triggered multiple times. Just bind your `viewModel` once.
You could verify that's the problem by calling : `ko.cleanNode($('#some-node')[0])` before appliying the bindings:

```
$('#idapiNumber').focusout(function () {

       ...
       ko.cleanNode($('#some-node')[0]);
       ko.applyBindings(new wellViewModel("", ""));
       ...
    });
```

Of course you would replace `#some-node` for the real selector.